# NIST STS randomness testing inconsistent results

Tags: randomness, nist

I have generated the nine datasets according to this [document](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=151193) for AES-128 and testing these for randomness using NIST STS. However, the results are inconsistent. Sometimes there appear a * in the result files and sometimes it doesnot. Even the result files show different values on multiple testing of the same file.

Why the behaviur is inconsistent?
Most of them times, test fails with a mrginal value e.g if passing crietria is 120/128, then result is 119/128 with a *. Can this marginal failing be ignored?

Comment: I encounter this issue too.
I run nist sts test suite with parameter ./assess 1000000 and bitstreams 100. I tested 20 different data samples. The result is some file pass some file failed.
I don't know what parameters should I use. Should all 20 data samples pass the test? or some may pass some may fail, is it normal?